# Dart/Flutter - Call constructor of unknown concrete class (get class from Type)

Tags: flutter, class, dart, types, interface

I want to call the constructor of a concrete class, but I only have a `Type` which implements an interface. Is it possible to get the concrete class from that `Type` and call its constructor without actually having to know it?

My current workaround is a switch with a cast, but that does not seem reasonable, because I have to maintain the switch whenever another class implements that interface.

```
abstract class IFace {
  String foo();
}

class Bar implements IFace {
  String foo() => 'I am Bar';
}

T? getObject<T extends IFace>() {
  // what I'd like to do, but does not work:
  // return T();
  
  // what I have to do instead:
  switch (T) {
    case Bar:
      return Bar() as T;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}


void main() {
  Bar? bar = getObject<Bar>();
  
  print(bar?.foo()); // I am Bar
}
```

Comment: Not possible in Dart. In general, you cannot do much with a `Type` in Dart.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy thing to do just because, what if T does not have public constructor, or it has named constructor instead? ;)

I think it could be possible only with use of dart:mirrors package, which is not available on Flutter (due to AOT compilation).

As alternative, you can try using  [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) package, but it is not easy to do either.

Comment: Indeed. The main problem is that an interface cannot dictate what constructor are available. So we cannot statically ensure that we can call a constructor on a given type.

Comment: That's where I'd like to have something more strict than an interface, so that I can define a constructor in a "super interface" and every class implementing that "super interface" must have the same constructor.

Comment: @Stacky Well, you need to rethink this design since this is not possible in Dart. I also don't think this feature is common in other programming languages?

Comment: Aside from some script languages, like JavaScript, this is not common I guess. But generic types aren't common either. At least not in "older" programming languages, which have not come out in the past 10 or so years.

Comment: This is possible with C++ templates, but templates are compiled very differently.